# Under what conditions is the resolvent set of a linear operator connected?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a Hilbert Space, and assume that $T: H \to H$ is a possibly unbounded linear operator whose domain $D(T)$ is a dense subspace of $H$.

As usual, we define the resolvent set $\rho(T) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ to be those $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $(T -z )^{-1} : H \to D(T)$ exists and is bounded with respect to the norm induced by the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. It is true that $\rho(T)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

> Under what conditions on the operator $T$ is $\rho(T)$ known to be a connected set? Is this a fairly well-understood question, or are there difficulties involved?

I haven't thought about this question before, and don't know exactly how to approach it. I am familiar with some tools from functional analysis, such as the version of the spectral theorem developed via resolutions of the identity (e.g., from Rudin's book).

The cleanest example I have in my mind is $- \Delta : H^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, whose spectrum is $[0, \infty)$, and hence has connected resolvent set.

Any insight or reference suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What notion of connectedness are you using? If you're talking about simple connectedness, your question requires absence of isolated eigenvalues. How restrictive do you want to be on operator classes? If $T$ is selfadjoint, then $\rho(T) \subset \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$ and it's connected if there's $\lambda \in \rho(T) \cap \mathbb R$. Now, since the spectrum of $T$ is contained in the closure of the numerical range of $T$, only unbounded selfadjoint operators can have a unconnected resolvent set. And semibounded operators like the laplacian don't have the full axis filled with spectrum

Comment: There are "sectorial operators" whose numerical ranges lie in a sector of angle < $\pi$.